# How to download and get video informations at the same time in youtube-dl?

Tags: youtube-dl

In youtube-dl cli, How can i get information about the video (in json output) while the video beign downloaded by the app?

When i use this command:

`youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNQXAC9IVRw`

It only shows me output filename, But what a about the duration, resolution, etc... ?

I do this with 2 requests, But is it possible in on go?

It would be great if it dump the video meta data into a json file as well as output filename, Because i also struggling to pragmatically get the path of downloaded file (i have to use regex)

Comment: This [youtue-dl documentation](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#output-template) has the various parameters listed.

Comment: Those are the options to customize output filename, I'm looking for a way to get video metadata for the downloaded file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `--print-json` in your command line.

```
youtube-dl --print-json https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNQXAC9IVRw
```

This outputs a big JSON, while video is still downloading